# dynamic time warping (dtw) for panel data

Tags: r, plot, pattern-matching, time-series, panel-data

For the following data frame,  I have calculated the cost matrix using the following codes.
Initially, I created a matrix with [i,j] entries are all 10. Then I filled the lower triangular part using dtw function to calculate the distances.

How can I make the upper triangular part of the "distmx" matrix as blank. I mean I want to delete the 10s in upper triangular part of the matrix "distmx".

For such data sets (panel data sets) how can I select the  query and reference series in order to plot it?

```
Lines <- "Ctry  year   Carx 
A 2000   13
A 2001    8
A 2002   12
A 2003   16
A 2004   10
A 2005   13
B 2000   20
B 2001   24
B 2002   32
B 2003   32
B 2004   30
B 2005   36
C 2000   42
C 2001   46
C 2002   45
C 2003   56
C 2004   56
C 2005   58
"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

cost matrix

```
library(dtw)

ulke <- unique(DF$Ctry)
distmx <- matrix(rep(10, length(ulke)*length(ulke)), ncol=length(ulke))
colnames(distmx)<-rownames(distmx)<-ulke

for (i in 1:length(ulke)){
  for (j in i:length(ulke)){

    distmx[j,i]<-dtw(DF[DF$Ctry== ulke[i],"Carx"], DF[DF$Ctry== ulke[j],"Carx"],       distance.only=TRUE)$distance

 }

}
```